# What to do when someone's edit changes the objective of my question?

Tags: discussion, edits

I just [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714458/hook-to-use-for-a-product-purchase-action-when-order-is-placed) about WooCommerce webhooks.  Overnight someone edited it to be about WooCommerce PHP hooks and answered the edited version.  But there is a big difference between these two!

WooCommerce PHP hooks call local PHP functions.

Webhooks trigger external HTTP requests.

Comment: Revert it, that's it.

Comment: Agreed - but do incorporate those parts of the edit that make the question better

Comment: BTW, why the php tag?

Answer (score 42):

**tl;dr**

1. Revert the edit
2. Comment on answers to advise of the edit
3. Optional: Ask the editor why - you might learn something.

---

As the original author, you have final say on what the post says and how it looks (with some restrictions - you can't go around vandalizing your posts or undoing good grammar only changes or adding unrelated noise back into the post).

So if someone had edited your post in a way you don't approve, you can always revert it to the previous state.  You should be mindful of any other improvements to the grammar and sentence structure that you would be undoing and try to incorporate them back into the post.  If an edit war ensues (if the user or another one tries to re-edit the post in the same way), then flag for a moderator, don't keep trying to revert the changes.

An added problem is what if someone answered the question while in its incorrect state.  Since that answer probably no longer addresses your actual question, you should leave a comment advising them of the edit.  A good and polite way to say it is something like

> Sorry but this doesn't actually address my question.  The question was actually about `Foo` but someone thought I was talking about `Bar` and edited my post to say that without my approval.  I have reverted the incorrect edit.

And if you received multiple answers, you should leave a comment on each.  The reason for this both to help the unsuspecting answerer avoid downvotes for answering the wrong question, but also prevent someone from seeing the wrong answer and trying to edit your post again (or prevent that answered from editing your post again since they might think you "changed" the question after they answered, rather than fixing the question.

---

The above is the general case on how to address this situation.  In your specific case, it looks like the editor is also the answerer, so there is one additional step I might perform, especially if the answerer appear to be an expert in the technology - I would ask them why they edited the question as they did.  The reason is they might know something you don't and you might learn the question you were asking wasn't the right question to ask originally.  I would still revert the edit first so they question addresses the problem you wanted to ask, but asking the editor might give you new insight into the problem, or at least point out why your question *might* be unclear so you can address any unclarity with a subsequent edit.

Comment: `3) Optional: Ask the editor why - you might learn something.` Respectfully disagree. If indeed the context of the question(or any question) is changed to then be answered in that new context, then there is nothing to learn. If anything, isnt that what comments are for? To clarify?... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @user919426 how do you know there is nothing to learn unlsss you ask? Maybe the question was unclear or you'll learn why it was unclear? Maybe what you asked isn't even possible so the editor mistakenly thought you were asking about an entirely different topic. Maybe you were asking the wrong question to solve the problem. Maybe the context that you think was so radically different isn't different at all? Sure, the editor should have commented first to clarify, no one is going to dispute that, but once the edit is made, all you can do is try to understand why and fix the question

Comment: You are right, after the fact the only thing you can do is seek clarification... But I still believe that there is nothing to learn in a scenario where the essence of your question is different. Retrospectively, if the editor believes you asked the wrong question, it is the editor who should seek clarification and correct then proceed to correct the person. I say so, because I had a similar scenario where it was marked a duplicate of a previously answered question, yet it wasn't my question...I made my case and the duplicate flag was removed, and re-answered by the same, kind editor :)

Comment: @user919426 to be honest, if you the there is nothing at all to learn, then you don't have to do the optional step 3. I personally think that to assume there is nothing to learn is a mistake and may be closing yourself off an opportunity